# How to use a private Repo with enviroment variables in a scala-cli Script

Tags: scala, scala-script, scala-cli

According to the [**scala-cli** doc](https://scala-cli.virtuslab.org/docs/reference/directives/#repository) you can define a Repo like this:

```
//> using repository "https://maven-central.storage-download.googleapis.com/maven2"
```

And you can specify environment variables like this:

```
//> using publish.secretKey "env:PUBLISH_SECRET_KEY"
```

However there is no directive for *repository.username*, so I need something like

```
//> using repository "https://env:MYUSER:env:MYPASSWORD@myprivaterepom.com"
```

Using the user and password directly works - but that is not really an option;).

Comment: Haven't tried this myself, but there is `repositories.credentials` in docs:
https://scala-cli.virtuslab.org/docs/guides/power/repositories/#repository-authentication